# Emulate XBOX360 buttons through code C#

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I have been Googling so much the past hours, and Im finally giving up. Basically what I want to do is to program a sequence of key strokes on my XBOX360 controller. I have been looking into XNA 4.0, but no luck there(yet!).

So if anyone have any kind of experience, or know something I should know. Ping me!

Comment: Maybe this gets you started: https://github.com/x360ce/x360ce

Comment: @Lucero Already been looking into that actually. Tried to make it work with AHK, but for some weird reason it didn't work to well. I just know there's some way to do it in XNA, I just have to discover how.. :/